# Корпус танка не должен поворачивать с башней

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть танк, на котором висит скрипт, который двигает его и поворачивает: "MainTankEngine". И так же есть скрипт который поворачивает башню за по оси "Y" за камерой.

Вот в чем проблема, когда я верчу танк на кнопки "A" и "D", башня вертится вместе с корпусом и у нее меняются координаты, и пушка остается на месте и вертится за камерой оттуда, где остановилась при повороте корпуса.

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы башня танка возвращалась назад при повороте корпуса. Или хотя бы чтоб при повороте корпуса, башня танка оставалась там, где и была до начала поворота корпуса.

Скрипт движения танка:

```
using UnityEngine;

//Script that moves and rotates the tank
public class MainTankEngine : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float speed = 10f;
   public float rotateSpeed = 10f;

   Rigidbody rb;

   public static float verticalMove;
   public static float rotateMove;

   private void Start()
   {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
   }

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
      Move();
      Rotate();
   }

   void Move()
   {
      verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
      Vector3 moveVertical = transform.forward * verticalMove * speed * Time.deltaTime;
      rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVertical);
   }

   void Rotate()
   {
      rotateMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
      if (verticalMove < 0)
         rotateMove *= -1f;
      Quaternion moveRotate = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotateMove, 0f);
      rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * moveRotate);
   }
}
```

Скрипт поворота башни:

```
using UnityEngine;

//Script that rotates the tower along the "Y" axis behind the camera
public class TowerRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Transform cam;
   public float speed = 50f;

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
      transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, cam.eulerAngles.y , 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
}
```

Ссылка на видео: https://youtu.be/Bh8hEGn1J8s

Comment: Если я в скрипте турели заменю "localRotation" на "rotation", то поворот башни работает как надо, но теперь когда я наезжаю на что-то, башня по осям "X" и "Z" не меняется и остается ровной, как будто она не принадлежит корпусу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не лучший вариант, конечно, но пока такой.

Турели добавил Rigidbody. Основа танка тоже с Rigidbody, но, в отличие от турели, кинематическая.

Всегда, когда будет начинаться поворот, турель повернёт в начальное положение (может, есть способ повернуть её плавно, но мне очень хочется спать).

```
using UnityEngine;

//Script that rotates the tower along the "Y" axis behind the camera
public class TowerRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cam;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    { 
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.parent.eulerAngles.y, 0));
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0)
        {
            rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, cam.eulerAngles.y, 0));
        }
    } 
}
```

*маленькая просьба присылать в следующий раз package или хотя бы ассеты, которые используешь*

Так, а вот более хороший вариант, без Rigidbody:

```
using UnityEngine;

//Script that rotates the tower along the "Y" axis behind the camera
public class TowerRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cam;
    public float speed = 50f, speedOfReturning;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    { 
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, transform.parent.rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, cam.eulerAngles.y, 0), speedOfReturning * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: isKinematic не подходит, так как нужно использовать рельеф

Comment: Да не суть. Главное было, чтобы поворачивало в координаты родителя.

Обновил ответ, посмотри код без Rigidbody.